# Mini-Max Sum on Hacker Rank C++

Tags: c++

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

```
void min_max(unsigned  long  int arr[]){
            unsigned  long  int max = arr[0];
            unsigned  long  int min = arr[0];
            for(int i=1; i<5; i++){
            if(arr[0] > arr[i]) min = arr[i];
            if(arr[0] < arr[i]) max = arr[i];
        }
        cout << min << " " << max;
    }

unsigned  long  int Sum(unsigned  long  int arr[], int n){
    unsigned  long  int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    sum = sum - arr[n];
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    unsigned  long  int arr[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    unsigned  long  int SUM[5];
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        SUM[j] = Sum(arr, j);
    }
    min_max(SUM);
}
```

If the input number is small, then my code has no problem, but when, let say, some really big numbers, like 293247447, then it says the test cases had failed. I don't know why, can someone help me please?

Comment: Note that if this was in an interview, the interviewer would ask "what if there were a thousand numbers, and you are to pick the 4 that adds to the min and max"?  I'm surprised hackerrank didn't throw that wrinkle into the question, as your solution with only 5 elements would probably time out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so what should i do if the interviewer asked me that, I was thinking about changing the for(int i=1; i<5; i++) to for(int i=1; i<n; i++), while n is any number the interviewer want me to input? is that correct or not? thank you

Comment: If `n` is 1000, you would be looping a million times, i.e. `O(n*n)`.  That is not efficient.  Anytime you are writing nested loops to solve a problem, it is usually not going to be efficient.  You should strive to get a logarithmic or even linear approach to the problem, not n*n.  The answer (which you didn't accept) of first sorting the data and simply taking the "middle" terms is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `min_max` function is wrong.  You're always comparing against `arr[0]`, which will only return the correct result if `arr[0]` is the smallest/second smallest (for min) or largest/second largest (for max) of the values.

The correct comparisons are

```
        if (min > arr[i]) min = arr[i];
        if (max < arr[i]) max = arr[i];
```

Or

```
        if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
        else if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
```

which makes it slightly easier to understand what is being done.  The `else` is optional but avoids the second comparison if the first is true (because the second will always be false if the first is true).

Answer (score 1):

You should know your algorithms. First sort the array with `std::sort`, then accumulate the 3 mid elements with `std::accumulate` and then add the first resp. last element:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using std::array;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    std::array<unsigned long int, 5> arr;
    for(auto &el : arr){
        cin >> el;
    }

    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    auto sum = std::accumulate(arr.begin() + 1, arr.end() - 1, 0);
    std::cout << arr[0] + sum << ' ' << arr[4] + sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution you will ever see , just two loops only but maybe high complexity `O(N*N)`

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr)
{
    // LLONG_MAX --> set min to the highest value in long long 
    // LLONG_MIN --> set max to the lowest value in long long but why lowest value ? because you want highest value
    long long min = LLONG_MAX , max = LLONG_MIN , sum ;
    for(int i = 0 ;i < arr.size() ; ++i)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.size() ; ++j)
        {
            if(i != j)
                sum += arr[j];
        }

        if(sum > max)
            max = sum;

        if (sum < min)
            min = sum;
    }

    cout << min << " " << max << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with complexity f(O2)

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {

   long long int l_lliMax = arr[0];
   long long int l_lliMin = arr[0];
   long long int l_lliSum = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
   {
       if(arr[i] > l_lliMax)
          l_lliMax = arr[i];

       if(arr[i] < l_lliMin)
          l_lliMin = arr[i];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
   {
      l_lliSum += arr[i];
   }

   cout << (l_lliSum - l_lliMax ) << " " << (l_lliSum - l_lliMin );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use stl for sorting, the rest is an example when developing your own.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array<unsigned long int, 5> arr = {5, 1, 2, 4, 3};
    unsigned long int min = 0, max = 0;
    
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    int maxIdx = static_cast<int>(arr.size() - 1);
    for (int i = 0, j = maxIdx; i < maxIdx; i++, j--) {
        min += arr[i];
        max += arr[j];
    }
    std::cout << min << " " << max << std::endl;
}
```